# Struts 2 JUnit Plugin v2.2.3: Test Class Extending StrutsTestCase; 'request' is null

Tags: plugins, struts2, junit4

I am attempting to use the Struts2 JUnit Plugin (v2.2.3 w/ Struts2 v2.2.3) and have run into several issues.

I attempted to use the [Struts2 JUnit Plugin Tutorial](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/struts-2-junit-plugin-tutorial.html) as a guide.  The first change I needed to make (not in the guide) is to annotate my test class with:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:applicationContext-test.xml"})
```

because I was getting the error when trying to run my unit test:

```
SEVERE:   [56:51.239] ********** FATAL ERROR STARTING UP STRUTS-SPRING INTEGRATION **********
Looks like the Spring listener was not configured for your web app! 
Nothing will work until WebApplicationContextUtils returns a valid ApplicationContext.
You might need to add the following to web.xml: 
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
SEVERE:   [56:51.254] Dispatcher initialization failed
```

This is different than the tutorial- does anyone know why I needed to do this?

I also had to add the following Spring Jars (I have the necessary Struts2 jars included in my classpath):

- spring-beans-2.5.6.jar
- spring-context-2.5.6.jar
- spring-core-2.5.6.jar
- spring-test-2.5.6.jar
- spring-web-2.5.6.jar

I do not use Spring w/in my struts app, but I assume these jars are needed to use the mock `request` object and such in the `StrutsTestCase`.

My Test class:

```
package com.actions;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.beans.LabelValueBean;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:applicationContext-test.xml"}) 
public class DocumentCategoryTest extends StrutsTestCase {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DocumentCategoryTest .class);

    /**
     * Testing RetrieveDocumentTypesForDocumentCategory
     * Expecting the List<LabelValueBean> is not null
     * @throws ServletException 
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException 
     */
    @Test
    public void testRetrieveDocumentTypesForDocumentCategory() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, ServletException {

        final String docCategory = "Employment";

        //set parameters
        request.setParameter("documentCategoryDescription", docCategory);   

        //execute the action
        executeAction("/recipient/RetrieveDocumentTypesForDocumentCategory.action");  

        //retrieve the document types
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<LabelValueBean> testDocTypeList = (List<LabelValueBean>) findValueAfterExecute("documentTypes");

        //make sure the document type list is not null and has at least one document type
        assertNotNull(testDocTypeList);
        assertTrue("At least one document type should exist for category 'Employment'", testDocTypeList.size() > 0);

        //print types
        log.debug("Document types for category '" + docCategory + "'");
        log.debug(testDocTypeList);
    }
}
```

When I execute the action, I get a `NullPointerException` on the `request.setParameter` piece of code:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.actions.DocumentCategoryTest.testRetrieveDocumentTypesForDocumentCategory(DocumentCategoryTest.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringTestMethod.invoke(SpringTestMethod.java:160)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTestMethod(SpringMethodRoadie.java:233)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie$RunBeforesThenTestThenAfters.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:333)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:217)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:197)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:143)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:160)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

This is because, for some reason, `request` is null in `StrutsTestCase`.  Why is this?  I'm doing exactly as the tutorial dictates!

My action class extends another class (`BaseAction`) that extends `ActionSupport` and implements `SessionAware`.

```
package com.actions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.actions.BaseAction;

/**
 * Retrieves the document types for the passed in document category
 */
public class DocumentIndexingData extends BaseAction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DocumentIndexingData.class);

    /*=========================================================================
     * FIELDS
     *=========================================================================*/
    /**
     * The description to use to look up the document types for that category
     */
    private String documentCategoryDescription;
    /**
     * List of document types for a category
     */
    private List<LabelValueBean> documentTypes;

    /*=========================================================================
     * PUBLIC METHODS
     *=========================================================================*/
    /**
     * Retrieves & sets list of document types for document category with passed in ID
     * 
     * @return If there is an error, document type will be set to ERROR; SUCCESS is always returned by this method
     */
    public String retrieveDocumentTypesForDocumentCategory() {      

        List<LabelValueBean> docTypes = new ArrayList<LabelValueBean>();

        //retrieve document types for passed in category ID
        log.debug("looking up document types for category: " + getDocumentCategoryDescription());   

                ////////////////
        //retrieve the document types for the document category here...
                ////////////////

        this.setDocumentTypes(docTypes);

        log.debug("document types found: " + getDocumentTypes());

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    /*=========================================================================
     * GETTERS/SETTERS
     *=========================================================================*/
    /**
     * Retrieves the list of document types
     * 
     * @return  list of document types
     */
    public List<LabelValueBean> getDocumentTypes() {
        return documentTypes;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the list of document types
     * 
     * @param documentTypes
     */
    public void setDocumentTypes(List<LabelValueBean> documentTypes) {
        this.documentTypes = documentTypes;
    }
    /**
     * Retrieves the document category to retrieve document types for
     * 
     * @return  the document category
     */
    public String getDocumentCategoryDescription() {
        return documentCategoryDescription;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the document category to retrieve document types for 
     * 
     * @param documentCategoryDescription   the document category to retrieve document types for 
     */
    public void setDocumentCategoryDescription(String documentCategoryDescription) {
        this.documentCategoryDescription = documentCategoryDescription;
    }
}
```

struts.xml entry:

```
<!-- indexing attributes action -->
<action name="RetrieveDocumentTypesForDocumentCategory" class="com.actions.DocumentIndexingData" method="retrieveDocumentTypesForDocumentCategory">
    <result type="json">
        <param name="root">documentTypes</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

I'm following the tutorial pretty closely, why is `request` null?  Thank you so much for any help!

**UPDATE (My Solution! via @Alex):**
I now only have the following Struts JARs included on my classpath:

- struts2-junit-plugin-2.2.3.jar
- spring-beans-2.5.6.jar
- spring-context-2.5.6.jar
- spring-core-2.5.6.jar
- spring-test-2.5.6.jar
- spring-web-2.5.6.jar

Sample test:

```
    public class MyTest extends StrutsTestCase {  

        @Test
        public void testMyAction() throws Exception {  

            request.setParameter("aParameter", "aValue");

            //create action proxy
            ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/test/MyAction");
            assertNotNull(proxy);       
            MyAction action = (MyAction) proxy.getAction();
            assertNotNull(action);

            //execute the action
            String result = proxy.execute();

            //make assertions, expecting success and no error messags   
            assertTrue("There should be no field errors: " + action.getFieldErrors(), action.getFieldErrors().size() == 0);
            assertTrue("There should be no action errors: " + action.getActionErrors(), action.getActionErrors().size() == 0);
            assertEquals("Result did not match expected value; ", Action.SUCCESS, result);
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not use Spring w/in my struts app, but I assume these jars are needed to use the mock request object and such in the StrutsTestCase.

Given the exception messages you're seeing above your application believes that it uses Spring. Do you have the Struts2-Spring-Plugin on your classpath? If you're not using Spring for IoC then you shouldn't include it on your classpath.

You should be able to test your actions by following guide you've referenced without any spring jars if you don't use Spring. Try removing all the spring jars and the struts2-spring-plugin jar. You also certainly don't need:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:applicationContext-test.xml"})
```

in your test class if you don't use spring.

Also check that your struts.xml doesn't contain this line:

`<constant name="struts.objectFactory"
value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory"/>`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply!  Removing the Struts2-Spring-Plugin from my classpath fixed my issues (along with removing my unneeded class annotations @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:applicationContext-test.xml"})) Thank you so much!

Comment: @Alex but what do you do when you want to test a struts action, that does use spring for dependency injection?

Comment: @Alex my code is throwing same NullPointerException , and also I need Struts2-SpringPlugin ,  So what will be the solution....? Please Help

Comment: I would recommend posting a new question for your specific problem.