# Struts2 session used in interceptor, why is it never null?

Tags: session, struts2

I use the Struts2 framework and I have a custom interceptor. The interceptor stack is the `defaultStack` + my custom interceptor at the bottom (right before the action). In the intercept method I use the following code:

```java
final ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext ();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST);
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

session.doSomething();
```

I was wondering why the used methods don't throw any exceptions, and why it isn't necessary to check `if(session != null)`. Is it not possible for those methods to fail to get an instantiated session? Why? Does the servlet-config interceptor have anything to do with this? If session *can* be `null`, in what kind of situation does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions are only rarely null, because:

1. Unless specifically configured not to, accessing any JSP page creates a session, and
2. You're calling `getSession(true)`, [which creates a session if one doesn't exist](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29).

There's a `"createSession"` interceptor you can add to the stack if you're running in an environment where a session *wouldn't* be created automatically. `"servletConfig"` is not directly involved.

Comment: Sessions can be null in case of testing.

Comment: @coding_idiot Then you're probably testing wrong, because of the reasons I listed.

Comment: you mean to say, that I should add `createSession` interceptor while testing. I use `StrutsJUnit4TestCase` while testing & I have to put session externally. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649952/struts2-3-12-junit4-testcase-request-session-are-null

Comment: @coding_idiot Personally, I either test my actions as POJOs and don't go through the entire request process (basically re-testing Struts 2 and Java EE), or I use a headless browser when I need full-on integration testing, which is both more realistic, and more complete.